# ¿Por que el body de mi objeto request esta vacío?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

He estado haciendo una app CRUD, utilice **express** para definir las rutas de mi app, cree rutas para notas **(get, post, put)** y no hubo problemas, intente hacer rutas para crear usuarios y almacenarlos, con **get** no hubo problema pero con **post** si,  hice un console.log para ver cual era el problemas y resulta que cuando hago un posteo de un usuario con su respectivos datos, lo registra como vacío, tengo las parte de mi código separado, pero este es el archivo donde pongo los **middlewares**

```js
const config = require("./utils/config")
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const notesRouter = require('./controllers/notes')
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("express-async-errors") 
const usersRouter = require("./controllers/users")
logger.info('connecting to', config.MONGODB_URI)

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger.error('error connecting to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('build'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(middleware.requestLogger)

app.use('/api/users', usersRouter)
app.use('/api/notes', notesRouter)

app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)
app.use(middleware.errorHandler)

module.exports = app
```

Este es el archivo donde defino las rutas

```js
const usersRouter = require("express").Router()

usersRouter.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  const notes = await Note.find({})
  response.json(notes)
})


usersRouter.post("/", (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body) // lo imprime como "{}"
})

module.exports = usersRouter
```

y este es el código que he ocupado para hacer la solicitud post

```js
POST http://localhost:3001/api/users

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "Mobml",
    "name": "Pedro Martinez",
    "password": "221433123124"
}
```

**Espero me puedan ayudar por favor**

Comment: ¿Cómo estás haciendo el post? ¿Desde un formulario? ¿Desde postman?

Comment: No de hecho estoy utiizando REST client para VS Code, pero  de igual manera si ocupo Postman ocurre lo mismo

Comment: Agrega `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` debajo de `app.use(express.json())` y dime si te funciona así.

Comment: Tal como te comentan, te falta el middleware para el análisis del cuerpo de la solicitud: `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: ... }));`

Comment: Ya intente hacerlo como me lo sugirieron pero de igual manera me sigue apareciendo vacío